# Dynamic rows in lightning component throwing error

Tags: lightning, dynamic, table

I'm trying to create a lightning component that will add and delete rows. I followed a tutorial available online and here is my code.

**Component:**

```
<aura:component controller="testCntrlr">
    <aura:attribute name="dailyTaskList" type="Daily_Task__c[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <div class="slds-box">
        <!--Table Part-->
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate">S.No</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="First Name">Task Type</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Last Name">Task Name</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Phone">Due Date</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Phone">Description</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Phone">Action</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.dailyTaskList}" var="item" indexVar="index">
                    <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                        <td>
                            {!index + 1}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <ui:inputText class="slds-input" value="{!item.Task_Type__c}"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <ui:inputText class="slds-input" value="{!item.Task_Name__c}"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <ui:inputPhone class="slds-input" value="{!item.Due_Date__c}"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <ui:inputPhone class="slds-input" value="{!item.Description__c}"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a onclick="{!c.removeRow}" id="{!index}">
                                <lightning:icon variant="error" iconName="utility:delete" class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" size="small" alternativeText="icon"/>
                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Delete Icon</span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <lightning:button variant="base" label="Add Row" title="Base action" onclick="{!c.AddNewRow}"/>
        <lightning:button variant="base" label="Submit" title="Base action" onclick="{!c.pushDetails}"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getPicklistOptions");
        var opts=[];
        action.setParams({
            'fieldName':'Task_Type__c',
            'sObjectName':'Daily_Task__c'
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            console.log(a.getState());
            console.log(JSON.stringify(a.getReturnValue()));
            component.set("v.options", a.getReturnValue());
            var RowItemList = component.get("v.dailyTaskList");
            RowItemList.push({
                "sobjectType":"Daily_Task__c",
                "Task_Name__c":"",
                "Description__c":"",
                "Daily_Update__c":"",
                "DE_Name__c":"",
                "Leave_From__c":"",
                "Leave_To__c":"",
                "Due_Date__c":"",
                "Created_Task_Date__c":"",
                "Closed__c":"",
                "Time_Required__c":""
            });
            // set the updated list to attribute (contactList) again
            component.set("v.dailyTaskList", RowItemList);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 

    },

    pushDetails: function(component, event, helper){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.dailyTaskList")));
        var action = component.get("c.getRecs");
        action.setParams({
            "dtc":component.get("v.dailyTaskList")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);   
    },

    AddNewRow : function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('Entered');
        var addRowInList = component.get("v.dailyTaskList");
        var contactObj = new Object();
        addRowInList.push(contactObj);
        component.set("v.dailyTaskList",addRowInList);
    },
    removeRow : function(component, event, helper){
        var whichOne = event.target.getAttribute("id")
        var AllRowsList = component.get("v.dailyTaskList");
        AllRowsList.splice(whichOne, 1);
        component.set("v.dailyTaskList", AllRowsList);
    },

    /*getTheWorkType: function(component, event, helper){
        var selectedValue = component.find('select').get('v.value');
        var usTable = component.find("usTable");

        if(selectedValue=='Training External'){
            $A.util.removeClass(usTable, 'slds-hide');
            $A.util.addClass(usTable, 'slds-show');

            var action = component.get("c.getUserStories");
            action.setCallback(this, function(response){
                component.set('v.userStories', response.getReturnValue());
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);   
        } else{
            $A.util.addClass(usTable, 'slds-hide');
            $A.util.removeClass(usTable, 'slds-show');

        }
    }*/
})
```

when I run this and enter data for two rows I am able to log only half data for second row.

Here is the output

[image]

please let me know where am i going wrong and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your inserting just normal JS object in to `Daily_Task__c[]` type in your   `AddNewRow` function, it's wrong you should insert `Daily_Task__c` sobject type what you did in success of doinit function. and addNewRow is Reusable function so as a best pratice you should declare `Daily_Task__c` sobject Aura attribute like below sample code.

**cmp**

```
<aura:attribute name="dailyTask" type="Daily_Task__c" default ="{ 'sobjectType':'Daily_Task__c'}"/>
```

**cmpcontroller**

```
AddNewRow : function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('Entered');
        var addRowInList = component.get("v.dailyTaskList");
        var contactObj = component.get("v.dailyTask");
        addRowInList.push(contactObj);
        component.set("v.dailyTaskList",addRowInList);
    },
```

you can use `dailyTask` attribute in `doint` function at `RowItemList.push` area also